# Mysql selects same column with different condition into same result row

Tags: mysql, database

I have a scenario of which requires to accumulate the rows data into single line of result row with condition of：

```
WorkIn = the earliest time from the a day when datetime captured.
LunchIn = the earliest time to lunch hour between 11:50:00 to 13:00:00
LunchOut = time latest time from lunch hour before 13:10:00
WorkOut = time captured the latest after 18:00:00
```

I have a set of data below:

```
id       timer
20605    2015-06-16 07:53:00
20605    2015-06-16 12:00:00
20605    2015-06-16 13:06:00
20605    2015-06-16 18:59:00
20605    2015-06-17 07:52:00
20605    2015-06-17 11:52:00
20605    2015-06-17 12:58:00
20605    2015-06-17 18:26:00
20605    2015-06-18 07:56:00
20605    2015-06-18 11:56:00
20605    2015-06-18 12:56:00
20605    2015-06-18 19:18:00
20211    2015-06-16 07:50:00
20211    2015-06-16 12:05:00
20211    2015-06-16 12:59:00
20211    2015-06-16 18:30:00
20211    2015-06-16 18:59:00
20211    2015-06-16 22:02:00
20211    2015-06-17 07:54:00
20211    2015-06-17 11:56:00
20211    2015-06-17 12:59:00
20211    2015-06-17 12:59:00
20211    2015-06-17 18:28:00
20211    2015-06-17 18:28:00
20211    2015-06-17 19:00:00
20211    2015-06-17 22:20:00
20211    2015-06-18 07:41:00
20211    2015-06-18 11:56:00
20211    2015-06-18 12:55:00
20211    2015-06-18 15:03:00
```

I would like to produce a result of :

```
id      clockIn               LunchIn               LunchOut              ClockOut
20605    2015-06-16 07:53:00    2015-06-16 12:00:00    2015-06-16 13:06:00    2015-06-16 18:59:00
20605    2015-06-17 07:52:00    2015-06-17 11:52:00    2015-06-17 12:58:00    2015-06-17 18:26:00
20605    2015-06-18 07:56:00    2015-06-18 11:56:00    2015-06-18 12:56:00    2015-06-18 19:18:00
20211    2015-06-16 07:50:00    2015-06-16 12:05:00    2015-06-16 12:59:00    2015-06-16 18:30:00
20211    2015-06-17 07:54:00    2015-06-17 11:56:00    2015-06-17 12:59:00    2015-06-17 12:59:00
20211    2015-06-17 18:28:00    2015-06-17 18:28:00    2015-06-17 19:00:00    2015-06-17 22:20:00
20211    2015-06-18 07:41:00    2015-06-18 11:56:00    2015-06-18 12:55:00    2015-06-18 15:03:00
```

I've tried union, multi select, but seems not producing the result I want.
Can anyone help?

Comment: What you tried so far

Comment: can you provide your sql please.

Comment: There seems to be [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10867780/select-multiple-sql-rows-into-one-row), but I think your question is sufficiently different to be not a duplicate. Your selection rule seems to be "for each `id` and date, select each group of four `timer`s, and if less than four `timer`s in the last group, discard them". Am I correct?

Comment: the data surely at least 4 timer in a row. If so happened less than 4,leave it blank.

Comment: I think this is a good question, but I cannot find an answer! I think experts would say that you cannot really do it in SQL, you should do it in the client (or in stored procedures).  You can use [`GROUP_CONCAT`](https://www.percona.com/blog/2013/10/22/the-power-of-mysqls-group_concat/) to decrease the client-side processing by batching up each day into a single row.

Comment: I didn't come out any sql at all, I just based on what the result I want, but couldn't figure out how to form the sql statement.